# Stop Bootstrap from resizing elements

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a search box with a button next to it:

[image]

But if the viewport gets smaller, the button pops underneath the input box:

[image]

How can I stop Bootstrap from obsessively resizing things in an unhelpful manner?

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle?

Comment: @Nitheesh not sure how - this is a VueJS project. If I view page source, I can't actually see any HTML because it was all generated by VueJS. And to replicate the problem I guess I need all the other elements in the row along to the left.

Comment: Any URL references?

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because bootstrap has applied `float` attribute on them and as viewport gets smaller it sets `float:none;`

You can avoid that by using `display:inline;` or `display:inline-block;` on such elements.

Comment: `display: inline` and `display:inline-block` on the parent div appears to have no effect whatsoever.

Comment: dont apply on the parent div. apply it to searchbox and textarea